# C# mediaelement not working after setup on other computer

Tags: c#, visual-studio

```
<Window x:Class="ErasmusWPF.Marta"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ErasmusWPF"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Marta" Height="768" Width="1366" ResizeMode="NoResize" WindowState="Maximized" AllowsTransparency="True" WindowStyle="None" Background="Transparent">

<Grid>

    <Image Source="Images\grass.jpg" Stretch="UniformToFill" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>

    <Image Source="Images\rail_luxury_shift-a.png" Height="833" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" OpacityMask="Black" Margin="-717,-38,-862,-27" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
    <Image Source="Images\Untitled.png" Margin="234,0,-369,-125" Width="1400" Height="767.8"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="636,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="566" LineHeight="18" TextAlignment="Center" FontSize="30"><Run Text="Klausīties Valka mūziku "/><LineBreak/><Run Text="(&quot;"/><Run Text="Dis"/><Run Text="t"/><Run Text="a"/><Run Text="nt Light&quot;)"/><LineBreak/><Run Text=" "/><InlineUIContainer/></TextBlock>
    <Button x:Name="button5" Content="" Margin="636,27,624,682" Click="button_Click">
        <Button.Background>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="Images/bcyEgxxzi.png"/>
        </Button.Background>
    </Button>
    <Button x:Name="play" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="484,322,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="140" Height="84" Click="play_Click" >
        <Button.Background>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="Images/playbutton.png"/>
        </Button.Background>
        <MediaElement x:Name="mediaElement" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="84" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="140" LoadedBehavior="Manual" UnloadedBehavior="Stop" Source="C:\Users\Leonards\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\ErasmusWPF\ErasmusWPF\ayylmao\crysis3.wmv" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Stretch="Fill" >

        </MediaElement>
    </Button>
    <Button x:Name="play2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="669,322,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="140" Height="84" Click="play2_Click" >
        <Button.Background>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="Images/playbutton.png"/>
        </Button.Background>
    </Button>
    <MediaElement x:Name="mediaElement2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="768" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1368" LoadedBehavior="Manual" UnloadedBehavior="Stop" Source="C:\Users\Leonards\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\ErasmusWPF\ErasmusWPF\ayylmao\crysis3.wmv" Margin="0,0,-2,0" Stretch="Fill"    />



</Grid>
</Window>
```

This is my xaml code

```
    public Marta()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }


    private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Media.SoundPlayer player =
        new System.Media.SoundPlayer();
        player.SoundLocation = @"C:\Users\Leonards\Documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ErasmusWPF\ErasmusWPF\Music\DistantLight.wav";
        player.Load();
        player.Play();
    }

    private async void play_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        mediaElement.Play();
        await Task.Delay (183000);
        mediaElement.Source = null;


    }

    private async void play2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        mediaElement2.Play();
        await Task.Delay(183000);
        mediaElement2.Source = null;
    } 
}
```

The problem begins when i try to run application on any other computer. Mediaelements are programmed for my computers C directory. Whenever louched on any other pc, the content is lost and missing.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. You're putting hard-coded absolute locations in your code/XAML, so obviously if they don't exist on another computer... well, they don't exist, hence your controls disappearing.

Comment: But if i use simplified location, then the video doesn't show up. It shows yellow warning sign on XAML.